# Axioms for homology and cohomology for CW complexes

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

This is related to assertion made in Hatcher, Algebraic Topology, Chpt 3, Sec 1 and Chpt 2.

I will write down axioms for cohomology and axioms for homology is written in a similar fashion.

> Cohomology theory for CW complexes is a sequence of contravariant functors with boundary map $\delta:H^n(A)\to H^{n+1}(X/A)$ where $(X,A)$ is a CW pair which implies $X/A$ makes sense as CW complex and it satisfies the following axioms.
>
> (1) If $f,g$ are homotopic, then $f,g$ induces same map on cohomology.
>
> (2) For each pair CW complex $(X,A)$, there is a induced long exact sequence by $...H^n(X/A)\to H^n(X)\to H^n(A)\to H^{n-1}(X/A)...$
>
> (3) For wedge sums of $X_i$ CW complexes, $X=\vee X_i$ for canonical inclusion $X_i\to X$, $H^\star(X)\cong\prod_iH^\star(X_i)$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ For Eilenberg-Steenrod Axioms, I do recall that for disjoint spaces $X=\bigsqcup X_i$, I have $H^\star(X)\cong\prod_i H^\star(X_i)$. How did disjoint union follows from above axioms? Note that I do not even have $H^i(pt)=0$ for $i\neq 0$ here and neither can I say $H^i(\bigsqcup x_j)=\bigoplus_jH^i(x_j)$ for $x_j$ being points. So I do not even see how to apply $(2)$.

Comment: If $X$ is a CW complex, then $(X,X)$ is a CW pair and 2) tells us that $H(pt) = H(X/X)$ is the kernel of an isomorphism, I.e. 0.

Comment: You can also get it from the wedge sum axiom since a point wedge a space is that space, and the induced inclusion map can only be an isomorphism if the cohomology of a point is trivial.

Comment: @RyleeLyman Maybe this is dumb question. Your argument seems reasonable but then your conclusion is basically saying this is axiom for reduced cohomology then? However, I have to say $(1)-(3)$ hold for non-reduced as well.  So $H^\star(pt)=0$ all the time?

Comment: @ConnorMalin Why is $H^\star(X\vee pt)\cong H^\star(X)\times H^\star(pt)$ implying $H^\star(pt)=0$? I could have $Z^N\cong Z^N\times Z$ by $N$ being natural number.

Comment: The axiom does not talk about an abstract isomorphism, but rather a specific one. If there is more than one element in the cohomology of a point the isomorphism is not surjective.

Comment: And are you assuming that this is a basepointed theory?

Comment: @ConnorMalin Then your context is "reduced" cohomology specifically here. The non-reduced cohomology functor also satisfies above property. For non-reduced cohomology, point does not have vanishing cohomology.

Comment: @ConnorMalin I do not think Hatcher means basepointed theory. If it is base pointed, then this would imply all cohomology should be trivial for the point which fits dimension axiom for ES criterion for free.

Comment: I think unreduced cohomology does not use basepoints, but reduced does. Unreduced talks about disjoint unions as an axiom, and the property of wedge sums (maybe above 0th dimension) follows from that. Reduced cohomology uses basepoints and so it talks about wedge sums as an axiom.

Comment: @ConnorMalin At beginning of the text, he said, "a (reduced) cohomology theory is a sequence of contravariant functors..." I guess he means it could be reduced or unreduced at the same time.

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes sense to ask about disjoint unions in the basepointed case, since you need to supply a basepoint to each component and I do not know if some cohomology theories assign different groups to the same space with different basepoints. I suspect they do not, but it would require showing you have a path from one basepoint to the other that's inclusion is a cofibration, and also the image is contractible.

Comment: This will be my last comment: I think you can give a simple argument in the connected case that this is true, but certainly not the disconnected case. So at most any statement about disjoint unions must be about disjoint unions of connected cw complexes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hatcher's approach is somewhat unusual, though it has the advantage of being very transparent. Hatcher defines a *reduced single space cohomology theory for unbased CW-complexes*. In fact, the occuring CW-complexes do not have basepoints, and there are no relative groups $H^n(X,A)$ but only single space groups $H^n(Z)$. The theory is reduced because all $H^n(pt) = 0$ (consider the exact sequence of the pair $(pt,pt)$ as in  Rylee Lyman's comment).

The Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms apply to theories defined on pairs. Therefore you have to associate to a cohomology theory in the sense of Hatcher a cohomology theory for CW-pairs. Note that this will be a generalized cohomology theory (which does not necessarily satisfy the dimension axiom). Given Hatcher's $H^n$, the usual approach is to define $\mathcal{H}^n(X,A) = H^n(X/A)$. For $A = \emptyset$ we interpret $X/A$ as $X^+$ = disjoint union of $X$ and an isolated  point not in $X$. You can show that this in fact a cohomology theory. The excision axiom has to be interpreted carefully because we can only excise $U \subset A$ such that $cl(U) \subset int(A)$ and $(X \setminus U, A \setminus U)$ is again a CW-pair.

Now you have $\mathcal{H}^n(X) = \mathcal{H}^n(X,\emptyset) = H^n(X^+)$. For $X = \bigsqcup X_i$ you get
$$\mathcal{H}^n(X) = H^n(X^+) = H^n(\bigvee X^+_i) \approx \prod H^n(X^+_i) = \prod \mathcal{H}^n(X_i) .$$